# Html.BeginForm() with only form Id is not generating correct action url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I only want to add the formId in the `beginForm()`

If i try using
`Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id="Id"})`

then the Html generated is
`<form action="/newquestion/payment/b9f88f80-f31f-4144-9066-55384c9f1cfc" ... >`

i don't know how that action url is generated so i tried,
`Html.BeginForm(new {@id="Id"})`
but then the action url looks like this
`<form action="/newquestion/payment/Id... >`

In both the cases the action url is not what it should be and it is not hitting the post action of the controller.

Comment: MVC uses the router to determine the URL's.  What is the URL supposed to be?

Comment: I don't want to set a fix controller and action in the BeginForm() because i want it to call the POST action based on the GET action. For example if i call payment (GET) then it should call payment (POST) and if i call Bundle (GET) then it should call Bundle (POST) action. This was working fine until now because i only had Html.BeginForm() but now i want to add the formId and that is breaking the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are trying to generate a route, such as with `BeginForm`, MVC will do its best to include things that you might need.

If you're at `domain.com/Home/Index/b9f88f80-f31f-4144-9066-55384c9f1cfc` and you use the code that you have provided than the form will be generated with the action, controller and route values as it finds them.

```
controller / action / id
/Home      / Index  / b9f88f80-f31f-4144-9066-55384c9f1cfc
```

One way to get around this is to force *id* to be nothing (such as an empty string).

Observe:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { @id = string.Empty },
    FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "Id" }))
{

}
```

The `new { @id = string.Empty }` is an anonymous object that represents the route values.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest. The code above works for me with MVC4 and MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

Change @id  to id.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm1" }))    
    {
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
```

Comment: What difference does it make?

Answer (score 1):

Because of in *System.Web.Mvc.Html*  ( in *System.Web.Mvc.dll* ) the begin form is defined like bellowed:-

> BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string
> controllerName,     object routeValues, FormMethod method, object
> htmlAttributes)
>
> **Means like this :** Html.BeginForm(
> string actionName, string    controllerName,     object routeValues,
> FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)

**So, it worked for me in MVC 4**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { @id = string.Empty }, FormMethod.Post,
    new { @id = "trainingForm" }))
{
    <input id="TRAINER_LIST" name="TRAINER_LIST" type="hidden" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```